# How can I interpolate values in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns in python. I want to enter the dataframe with one column and obtain the value of the 2nd column. Sometimes the values can be exact, but they can also be values between 2 rows.

I have this example dataframe:

```py
    x   y
0   0   0
1   10  100
2   20  200
```

I want to find the value of y if I check the dataframe with the value of x. For example, if I enter in the dataframe with the value of 10, I obtain the value of 100. But if I check with 15, I need to interpolate between the two values of y. Is there any function to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`numpy.interp` is probaly the simplest way here for linear interpolation:

```
def interpolate(xval, df, xcol, ycol):
# compute xval as the linear interpolation of xval where df is a dataframe and
#  df.x are the x coordinates, and df.y are the y coordinates. df.x is expected to be sorted.
    return np.interp([xval], df[xcol], df[ycol])
```

With your example data it gives:

```
>>> interpolate(10, df, 'x', 'y')
>>> 100.0
>>> interpolate(15, df, 'x', 'y')
>>> 150.0
```

You can even directly do:

```
>>> np.interp([10, 15], df.x, df.y)
array([100., 150.])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the `interpolate` method provided in `Pandas` module [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html). But I'm not sure that answers your question.

You can do it with `interp1d` from the `sklearn` module. Several types of interpolation are possible: ‘linear’, ‘nearest’, ‘zero’, ‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’... You find the list at the [(doc page)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d).

The interpolation process can be summarised as three steps:

1. Split your data between **missing** and **non missing values**. I use `isna` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)
2. **Create the interpolation function** using the data without missing values. I use `interp1d` [(doc)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d)
3. **Interpolate** (predict the missing values). Just call the function find in step 2 on the missing data (column `x`).

Here the code:

```
# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0,   0],
     [10, 100],
     [11, np.NaN],
     [15, np.NaN],
     [17, np.NaN],
     [20,   200]],
    columns=["x", "y"])
print(df)
#     x      y
# 0   0    0.0
# 1  10  100.0
# 2  11    NaN
# 3  15    NaN
# 4  17    NaN
# 5  20  200.0

# Split data in training (not NaN values) and missing (NaN values)
missing = df.isna().any(axis=1)
df_training = df[~missing]
df_missing = df[missing].reset_index(drop=True)

# Create function that interpolate missing value (from our training values)
f = interp1d(df_training.x, df_training.y)

# Interpolate the missing values
df_missing["y"] = f(df_missing.x)
print(df_missing)
#     x      y
# 0  11  110.0
# 1  15  150.0
# 2  17  170.0
```

You can find others works on the topic at this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html).